# Login System in PHP for multi user

Tags: php, mysql

I am making a login system in php xampp. After correct authentication of the user they get redirected depending on what role they play. For Admin it goes to Admin Page and for Sales Person it goes to the main menu. In the code below you can see how the login is setup. Now my problem is: For example more than one user login as Sales they will be redirected to the main menu page. Now lets say user x logs in first then user y logs in. Now both are at the main menu page. Now when I refresh the page of the main menu I see user y's name even though I am as user x and on the same main menu page.

```html
function Encrypt($Word)
{ //Encryption method

    $ciphering = "AES-128-CTR"; //method of encryption
    $options = 0;
    // Non-NULL Initialization Vector for Encryption 
    $Encryption_iv = '1234567891011121';

    // Store the Encryption key 
    $Encryption_key = "GeeksforGeeks";

    // Use openssl_Encrypt() function to Encrypt the data 
    return openssl_encrypt($Word, $ciphering, $Encryption_key, $options, $Encryption_iv);
}

//Getting user information. SQL injection protection and XSS Attack.
$username = (htmlspecialchars(mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['user'])));
$password = htmlspecialchars(mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['pass']));
/* $UserOption = (htmlspecialchars(mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Level'])));
$PinCode = htmlspecialchars(mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Pin'])); */
$Option = htmlspecialchars(mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['option']));

$Hash = Encrypt($username);
$SalesHash = Encrypt($username);

$GetActivestmt = $con->prepare("SELECT Active FROM logins WHERE Username=?");
$GetActivestmt->bind_param("s", $Hash);
$GetActivestmt->execute();
$ActiveResult = $GetActivestmt->get_result();
//Fetching
if ($ActiveResult->num_rows === 0) exit("No Records");
while ($Active = $ActiveResult->fetch_assoc()) {
    $ActiveRow = $Active['Active'];
}

$GetActivestmt->close();
global $ActiveRow;

$con->next_result();

/* if($UserOption == $row['User_Type'] && $Hash==$row['Username'] && password_verify($password, $row['HashPassword'])
&& $PinCode ==$row['PinCode']){
   
    echo $row['User_Type'];
}else if($UserOption == $row['User_Type'] && $Hash==$row['Username']
&& password_verify($password, $row['HashPassword']) && $PinCode == $row['PinCode']){
    echo $row['User_Type'];
}else{
    echo '<script>alert("Info Mis-Match");</script>';
    exit();
} */


if ($ActiveRow === 0) {

    $GetLoginstmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM logins WHERE Username=? LIMIT 1;");
    $GetLoginstmt->bind_param("s", $Hash/* , $PinCode */);
    $GetLoginstmt->execute();
    $LoginResult = $GetLoginstmt->get_result();

    //Fetching
    if ($LoginResult->num_rows === 0) exit('<script>alert("User not found");</script>');
    while ($Login  = $LoginResult->fetch_assoc()) {
        $Username = $Login['Username'];
        $HashPassword = $Login['HashPassword'];
        $UserType = $Login['User_Type'];
        $Pin = $Login['PinCode'];
        $ID = $Login['ID'];
    }

  $GetLoginstmt->close();
    global $Username, $HashPassword, $UserType, $Pin;

    echo "<script>alert('$Username');</script>";
    
    $con->next_result();

    if (
        $Hash == $Username && password_verify($password, $HashPassword)
        && $Option == $UserType
    ) {
        echo "<br/>";

        if ($Option == "Admin") {

            $UpdateItems = mysqli_query($con, "CALL Update_Items('$Hash')");

            if ($UpdateItems) {
                $_SESSION['HashUsername'] = $Hash;

                $_SESSION['datetime'] = date('Y/m/d'); //storing date in datetime session
                $url = "../PinCodes/VerifyPinForm.php"; //url to be redirected
                echo '<script language="javascript">window.location.href ="' . $url . '"</script>'; //redirects the user to the main page 
            } else {
                echo "Error in Query";
            }
        } else if ($Option == "Sales") {
            $UpdateItems = mysqli_query($con, "CALL Update_Items('$SalesHash')");
            if ($UpdateItems) {
                $_SESSION['SalesHash'] = $Username;
                $_SESSION['User_ID'] = $ID;
                // setcookie("Username", $Hash, time()+84600, "/", '', '', true); 
                $_SESSION['datetime'] = date('Y/m/d'); //storing date in datetime session
                $url1 = "../MainMenu/main.php";
                echo '<script language="javascript">window.location.href ="' . $url1 . '"</script>';
            }
        } else {
            echo "Error";
        }
    } else {
        echo '<script>alert("Incorrect User Info");</script>';
    }
} else {
    echo '<script>alert("User Already Logged in.");</script>';

    global $username, $password, $Option;

    $_SESSION['HashUsername'] = $Hash;
    $_SESSION['datetime'] = date("Y/m/d");
    $_SESSION['SalesHash'] = $SalesHash;

    if ($Option ==  "Sales") {
        $UpdateItems = mysqli_query($con, "CALL Update_Items('$SalesHash')");
        if ($UpdateItems) {
            $url1 = "../MainMenu/main.php";
            echo '<script language="javascript">window.location.href ="' . $url1 . '"</script>';
        }
    } else if ($Option == "Admin") {
        $UpdateItems = mysqli_query($con, "CALL Update_Items('$Hash')");
        if ($UpdateItems) {
            $url1 = "../PinCodes/VerifyPinForm.php";
            echo '<script language="javascript">window.location.href ="' . $url1 . '"</script>';
        }
    }
}


$con->close();

?>
```

```html
<?php

require '../connection1.php';

function Decrypt($Word)
{ //decrypting data using openssl decrypt method
    $ciphering = "AES-128-CTR";
    $options = 0;
    // Non-NULL Initialization Vector for decryption 
    $decryption_iv = '1234567891011121';
    // Store the decryption key 
    $decryption_key = "GeeksforGeeks";
    // Use openssl_decrypt() function to decrypt the data 
    return openssl_decrypt($Word, $ciphering, $decryption_key, $options, $decryption_iv);
}

if ($con) {
    session_regenerate_id(true);

    $User = $_SESSION['SalesHash'];
    $UserID = $_SESSION['User_ID'];
    $GetInfo = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM logins WHERE Username=? AND ID=?");
    $GetInfo->bind_param("si", $_SESSION['SalesHash'], $_SESSION['User_ID']);
    $GetInfo->execute();
    $GetResult = $GetInfo->get_result();

    //Fetch info
    if ($GetResult->num_rows === 0) exit(header("Location: ../Login/LogoutForm.html"));
    while ($row = $GetResult->fetch_assoc()) {
        $Active = $row['Active'];
        $Username = $row['Username'];
        $LoginTime = $row['Last_Login'];
        $UserType = $row['User_Type'];
        $ID = $row['ID'];
    }
    $GetInfo->close();
    global $Active, $Username, $LoginTime;
}

if ($Active == 1 && $UserType == "Sales" && $Username == $User) {
} else {
    header("Location: ../Login/Logout.html");
}


?>
```

This code is the main menu page. Now I don't know where I am going wrong.

I have started the session from xampp php.ini file.

Comment: What have you tried to archive this ? SO is not free code writing service - you need to show us code or example on what you have tried first and where are you stuck at - so someone can you help out. Do you own research as well here: https://stackoverflow.com/search - Read here how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @AlwaysHelping he did say he doesnt know where to start. Sometimes the right answer to a general quesiton is a helpful steps on how to approach the problem.

Comment: user x and y have their own separate sessions, it's built that way and you do not need to code anything

Comment: @Citizen How are you so sure that what he wanted at all ? The question itself is incomplete without knowing the laravel versions etc etc and full background you have answered already. Thats is not ideal at all :)

Comment: @AlwaysHelping maybe I don't actually. I updated my answer to reflect the two possible scenarios.

Comment: @Citizen Thanks alot. You did the right thing - this question needs alot clarity and more focus instead of an answer.

Comment: I have fixed my question.

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't need to store each salesperson in a session. What you want to do is store one user in the session, then have that user have access to many salespersons.

For instance your user table might have id, email address and password columns.

Then, your salespersons table would have id, user_id, and name.

In you session, you'd store which user_id was logged in. Then, one your page you could query something like `SELECT * FROM salespersons WHERE user_id = $session['user_id']`

If you use a modern PHP framework like Laravel you can handle this easily with relationships:

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships

User authentication also comes baked out of the box:

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication

Edit: maybe I'm misunderstanding your question. If you dont want one user to access multiple salespeople, you don't need to worry about separating the sessions. A session by it's nature is a single user accessing your service. If you research how php sessions work there's a ton of resources out there to help get you started.

Comment: I have fixed my question,